# Finding a user who ran a DROP COLUMN statement

Tags: sql-server

Here is the code I am working with:

```
USE [ExperimentalDB]
GO

--Create table tblTestEmployee
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTestEmployee]
(
    [EmployeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)

--Populate some records to the tblTestEmployee
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTestEmployee] 
VALUES('Emp1','Address1'),('Emp2','Address2'),('Emp3','Address3'),('Emp4','Address4')

--Drop the column Address
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblTestEmployee] DROP COLUMN [Address] --ONLY this

--Drop the table
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tblTestEmployee] -- NOT  THIS

--Find who has done that
SELECT [Transaction Id], [Begin Time], SUSER_SNAME ([Transaction SID]) AS [User],[Transaction Name],Operation,[Transaction SID]
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
```

My objective is to find out who has dropped the column [Address]

But by looking into the output of **fn_dblog**, I am not able to figure out properly.

Comment: I created [dbhistory.com](http://dbhistory.com) to answer such questions.

Comment: Relevant question on DBA stack https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10716/3690

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to display all logs involved with `DROP` command

```
GO
SELECT 
Operation,
[Transaction Id],
[Transaction SID],
[Transaction Name],
[Begin Time],
[SPID],
Description
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ'
GO
```

Take the **transaction SID** from the above resultset and pass it to system function `SUSER_SNAME()` to get the exact user name:

`SELECT SUSER_SNAME(SID)`

Comment: @!Aishvarya Karthik, but I want to know only who has deleted the column

Comment: The 2nd query will give you the result

Comment: Right, i am getting the result but want to know only which user has deleted the column and not any other stuff like table etc.

Comment: Operation Transaction Id Transaction SID Transaction Name Begin Time SPID Description (No column name)
LOP_BEGIN_XACT 0000:00000a37 0x01 DROPOBJ 2015/11/06 10:31:12:803 53 DROPOBJ;0x01 sa
LOP_BEGIN_XACT 0000:00000a3f 0x01 DROPOBJ 2015/11/06 10:31:13:577 53 DROPOBJ;0x01 sa
LOP_BEGIN_XACT 0000:00000a46 0x01 DROPOBJ 2015/11/06 10:31:38:400 53 DROPOBJ;0x01 sa
LOP_BEGIN_XACT 0000:00000a4d 0x01 DROPOBJ 2015/11/06 10:35:01:477 53 DROPOBJ;0x01 sa

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar, http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/audit-sql-server-database-and-see-who-deleted-a-column-value/ might help